How to delete white separator or border from line scatter plotly.js, when there are a lot of points?
I use plotly.js, scatter line graph for horizontal timeline
var trace1 = {
  x: [1726046102344, 1726051503518],
  y: [0, 0],
  mode: "lines",
  type: "scatter",
  line: {
    color: "black",
    width: 100
  },
};

var layout = {
  xaxis: { type: "date" },
  yaxis: { showticklabels: false },
  showlegend: false,
  height: 100,
  margin: { l: 20, r: 20, b: 40, t: 10, pad: 0 }
};

But when there are a lot of traces, there is appear white gap between lines enter image description here,
when I zoom it, there is no white gap
enter image description here
https://codepen.io/mikhaylenkoannai/pen/RwzXmdd
So, how can i delete this white gap?

I don't know what the actual problem is, but playing around with your codepen showed, that reducing the line width from 100 to 40 avoids the white gaps.
